# What kinds of whitespace are visualized in Whitespace mode?

Tags: whitespace-mode

According to the Emacs manual (section 14.16 Useless Whitespace):

> The kinds of whitespace visualized [in `whitespace` mode -- Evan] are determined by the list variable `whitespace-style`.

However, when I execute `C-h v whitespace-style RET`, no match is found.

How can I view the list of whitespace visualized in `whitespace` mode?

Comment: Try `(require 'whitespace)` first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the docstring of `whitespace-mode` (emphasis mine):

> whitespace-mode is an interactive **autoloaded** compiled Lisp function in
>   ‘whitespace.el’.
>
> (whitespace-mode &optional ARG)
>
> Toggle whitespace visualization (Whitespace mode).
>   ...

The elisp [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Autoload.html#Autoload) section on autoloading begins with:

> The autoload facility lets you register the existence of a function or macro, but put off loading the file that defines it. The first call to the function automatically loads the proper library, in order to install the real definition **and other associated code**, then runs the real definition as if it had been loaded all along.

So in this case, although the function `whitespace-mode` is visible, the `whitespace` library is not loaded and so variable `whitespace-style` is not defined.  You can autoload the library by invoking function `whitespace-mode`, for example with `M-x whitespace-mode`.